# Add User RHEL ubi8/openjdk-8 Docker Image fails

Tags: linux, docker, rhel

While updating some Docker Baseimages (which previously were based on this image `openjdk/openjdk-8-rhel8`) to this image: `ubi8/openjdk-8` I (suspect that I) was unable to add a user with the `useradd` cammand.

It appears inside the /etc/shadow file, but when I try to login into the container I get that messenge:

```
NWRAP_ERROR(4677) - nwrap_files_cache_reload: Unable to open '/home/jboss/passwd' readonly -1:Permission denied
NWRAP_ERROR(4677) - nwrap_files_getpwuid: Error loading passwd file
```

the Dockerfile, which worked well with the previous Image is:

```
FROM xxxx.azurecr.io/ubi8/openjdk-8:1.3-9


ARG uid=60000
ARG gid=60000
ARG user=testuser
ARG group=testuser
ARG shell=/bin/bash
ARG home=/home/$user
ARG port=8080

USER root
RUN mkdir -p $home \
  && chown ${uid}:${gid} $home \
  && groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
  && useradd --uid ${uid} --gid ${gid} --shell ${shell} --home ${home} $user
```

I don't know what could cause that problem, and  searching for `NWRAP_ERROR(4677)` gave me no results. Dis someone had similar problems and could tell what went wrong and if there is a different way to add the user with the Dockerfile?

Comment: When you say "log in", what action are you actually performing?  (A Docker container only runs one process, and it's not typically something that accepts interactive logins.)

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong wording, - I mean a "docker exec -it <CID> bash"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with this image when I tried to :

```
[root@3ee1b7206f33 ~]# useradd -m -u 15001 myaccount_azpcontainer
[root@3ee1b7206f33 ~]# groupadd azure_pipelines_sudo
[root@3ee1b7206f33 ~]# usermod -a -G azure_pipelines_sudo myaccount_azpcontainer
usermod: user 'myaccount_azpcontainer' does not exist
```

if I look in /ect/passwd, the user is present :

```
[root@3ee1b7206f33 ~]# cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:Kernel Overflow User:/:/sbin/nologin
jboss:x:185:0:JBoss user:/home/jboss:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
systemd-coredump:x:999:997:systemd Core Dumper:/:/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:193:193:systemd Resolver:/:/sbin/nologin
unbound:x:998:996:Unbound DNS resolver:/etc/unbound:/sbin/nologin
myaccount_azpcontainer:x:15001:15001::/home/myaccount_azpcontainer:/bin/bash
```

but usermod doesn't work and getent passwd doesn't work

```
[root@3ee1b7206f33 ~]# getent passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:Kernel Overflow User:/:/sbin/nologin
jboss:x:185:0:JBoss user:/home/jboss:/sbin/nologin
```

I have no problem with others redhat images, only with openjdk

By looking the image DockerFile I found :

```
USER root
RUN [ "sh", "-x", "/tmp/scripts/jboss.container.user/configure.sh" ]
```

and the content of file :
https://github.com/jboss-openshift/cct_module/blob/master/jboss/container/user/configure.sh

```
groupadd -r jboss -g 185 && useradd -u 185 -r -g root -G jboss -m -d /home/jboss -s /sbin/nologin -c "JBoss user" jboss
cp /etc/passwd /home/jboss/passwd
chmod ug+rwX /home/jboss /home/jboss/passwd
```

I tested it in mydockerfile and add cp /etc/passwd /home/jboss/passwd after useradd and It works !!

My colleague explained me the problem is the usage of nss_wrapper :https://cwrap.org/nss_wrapper.html

Maybe, there is another way to manage the useradd, but not yet tested

Thanks,

Comment: I had the same issue. If you see NSS_WRAPPER_PASSWD is set to /home/jboss/passwd. Adding these after user creation worked for me:  cp /etc/passwd /home/jboss/passwd && \
chmod 777 /home/jboss /home/jboss/passwd

Comment: The issue was resolved for me by using the image from "registry.redhat.io/ubi9/openjdk-11:1.13-8.1667372120" instead of "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-11:1.3-15".  But you will need an account to download the images from "egistry.redhat.io".